# how to create multidimensional array from CSV in Python

Tags: python, arrays, csv, plot

I want to create multidimensional table from CSV file. It should be grouped by two concatenated column. My CSV file has a structure (data is my imagination):

```
Year,Country,Sex,Population
1990,USA,M,178
1990,USA,F,179
2000,USA,M,180
2000,USA,F,181
1990,France,M,51
1990,France,F,52
2000,France,M,51
2000,France,F,53
```

I need to show that data on plot using matplotlib so I decided to create three multidimensional table where year is X axis, population is Y axis, and concatenated country and sex is label.

[image]

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a code writing service, please take the time to look through the ['asking' help articles](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and then edit your post with a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

There is two main ways to do it really. Doing it with pandas or hardcoding it. I prefer doing it with pandas. Here's an example:

```
import pandas
df = pandas.read_csv('data.csv')
print(df)
```

This will give you the easiest result. Now there's a few ways to access the data. But you might not even need this depending if you continue to develop this app. But still you can access the created pandas DataFrame by using:

```
# Using `iloc[]`
print(df.iloc[0][0])

# Using `loc[]`
print(df.loc[0]['Sex'])

# Using `at[]`
print(df.at[0,'Population'])

# Using `iat[]`
print(df.iat[0,0])
```

This is how you make a multidimensional "array" with pandas. I put it in quotes because it's a dataframe that's created not an array actually. Hopefully it helps you to develop this program. I would suggest reading how you can plot this with matplotlib and pandas in this tutorial https://queirozf.com/entries/pandas-dataframe-plot-examples-with-matplotlib-pyplot

Answer (score 0):

You should use [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module for this. This works great for me.

- First we save the data in a CSV file in `data.csv`.
- Then import csv module and append each row of csv into an empty ndarray

```py
import csv

arr = []

with open("data.csv") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC) # change contents to floats
    for row in reader: # each row is a list
        arr.append(row)

print(arr)
```

- This outputs the desired multidimentional array

```py
[['Year,Country,Sex,Population'],
 ['1990,USA,M,178'],
 ['1990,USA,F,179'],
 ['2000,USA,M,180'],
 ['2000,USA,F,181'],
 ['1990,France,M,51'],
 ['1990,France,F,52'],
 ['2000,France,M,51'],
 ['2000,France,F,53']]
```